# Rails mutlipe has_many through different models to single model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I need some help in framing rails models.
I have four models User,Product,UserSavedProduct,likedProduct.

Users can have many products through usersavedproducts and liked products,these are my models. Is this the correct way to write them. If so how to get all saved products,Liked products of single user,else can you point me in right direction.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_saved_products

  has_many :saved_products,:through => :user_saved_products,:source => :products

  has_many :product_likes

  has_many :products,:through => :product_likes

End


class UserSavedProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :product

end

class ProductLike < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :product

end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :user_saved_products

  has_many :users, :through => :user_saved_products

  has_many :product_likes

  has_many :users,:through => :product_likes

end
```

When  I do  User.first.methods.grep(/product/)

=> [:autosave_associated_records_for_user_saved_products, :validate_associated_records_for_user_saved_products, :before_add_for_user_saved_products, :before_add_for_user_saved_products?, :before_add_for_user_saved_products=, :after_add_for_user_saved_products, :after_add_for_user_saved_products?, :after_add_for_user_saved_products=, :before_remove_for_user_saved_products, :before_remove_for_user_saved_products?, :before_remove_for_user_saved_products=, :after_remove_for_user_saved_products, :after_remove_for_user_saved_products?, :after_remove_for_user_saved_products=, :autosave_associated_records_for_saved_products, :validate_associated_records_for_saved_products, :before_add_for_saved_products, :before_add_for_saved_products?, :before_add_for_saved_products=, :after_add_for_saved_products, :after_add_for_saved_products?, :after_add_for_saved_products=, :before_remove_for_saved_products, :before_remove_for_saved_products?, :before_remove_for_saved_products=, :after_remove_for_saved_products, :after_remove_for_saved_products?, :after_remove_for_saved_products=, :autosave_associated_records_for_product_likes, :validate_associated_records_for_product_likes, :before_add_for_product_likes, :before_add_for_product_likes?, :before_add_for_product_likes=, :after_add_for_product_likes, :after_add_for_product_likes?, :after_add_for_product_likes=, :before_remove_for_product_likes, :before_remove_for_product_likes?, :before_remove_for_product_likes=, :after_remove_for_product_likes, :after_remove_for_product_likes?, :after_remove_for_product_likes=, :autosave_associated_records_for_liked_products, :validate_associated_records_for_liked_products, :before_add_for_liked_products, :before_add_for_liked_products?, :before_add_for_liked_products=, :after_add_for_liked_products, :after_add_for_liked_products?, :after_add_for_liked_products=, :before_remove_for_liked_products, :before_remove_for_liked_products?, :before_remove_for_liked_products=, :after_remove_for_liked_products, :after_remove_for_liked_products?, :after_remove_for_liked_products=, :user_saved_products, :user_saved_product_ids, :user_saved_products=, :user_saved_product_ids=, :saved_products, :saved_product_ids, :saved_products=, :saved_product_ids=, :product_likes, :product_like_ids, :product_likes=, :product_like_ids=, :liked_products, :liked_product_ids, :liked_products=, :liked_product_ids=]

Comment: First argument of `has_many` is a base name for a bunch of methods related to association. That is, you shouldn't define multiple associations with the same names, as it's done in `Product` with `:users`. Apart from that, everything seems fine, but what's the question? Have you tried these associations? Do they work as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you have is in your Product model - you have multiple `:users` associations.  I would set it up like so.

I had to choose two association names from products back to users.  I chose `liking_users` and `saving_users`, you can rename these if you don't like them.

If i was doing this i would rename the ProductLike class to "UserLikedProduct" to make it consistent with "UserSavedProduct".  Obviously if you do this you'll need to change the database table name and the associations which reference the table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_saved_products
  has_many :saved_products, :through => :user_saved_products, :class_name => "Product"
  has_many :product_likes
  has_many :liked_products,:through => :product_likes, :class_name => "Product"
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_saved_products
  has_many :saving_users, :through => :user_saved_products, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :product_likes
  has_many :liking_users, :through => :product_likes, :class_name => "User"
end    

class UserSavedProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end

class ProductLike < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But when I do User.first.saved_products in my rails console it's not working and the error is "undefined method saved_products". Is this the correct way to do it?.

Comment: Have you restarted your console after making the changes?

Comment: I restarted the server and this was the error User.first.saved_products
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`   ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Does `User.first` return a User object?

Comment: Yes williams it is returning a object. Please tell me if you need any more information.

Comment: what is the result of `User.first.methods.grep(/product/)`?  What is the result of `User.first.user_saved_products`?

Comment: User.first.saved_products is return a object from user_saved_products table but User.first.method.grep(/product/) is not retuning anything.

Comment: i said `methods` not `method`

Comment: Also i said `User.first.user_saved_products` not `User.first.saved_products`.  I'd expect this to return an array of UserSavedProduct objects (which may be empty).

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake . When I do User.first.user_saved_products it's returning as you expected and as for User.first.methods.grep(/product/) I have added the result to the question.

Comment: Thanks williams for your help but I don't have enough points to upvote your answer .It worked when I changed :class_name to :source.

Comment: ah - sorry, that must be a rails version thing.